# Why is this not working in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have these two dropdowns:

```
<select class="cityId form-control" dir="rtl">
@foreach (var city in Paristan.AgencyPortal.UI.Areas.Cpanel.Components.DropdownHelper.GetCities())
{
    <option value="@city.Value">@city.Text</option>
}
</select>
<select name="travelAirports" class="airports form-control" dir="rtl">
    <option>Select a City</option>
</select>


$(document).on("change", ".cityId", function () {
        $.getJSON("/Cpanel/Package/GetAirportsByCityId", { cityId: $(this).val() }, function (data) {
        $(this).next(".airports").empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        $(this).next(".airports").append("<option value='" + data[i].AirportId + "'>" + data[i].Name + "</option>");
        }
    });
});
```

The ajax function is working. But I can not catch the next dropdown with the written selector. Even the followings are not helping me:

```
$(this).parent().children().first().next()
$(this).parent().children(".airports")
$(this).nextAll(".airports")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` in the ajax callback does not refer to the changed `cityId` element, it refers to the ajax setting object used for making the request.

You can use a closure variable to fix this like

```
$(document).on("change", ".cityId", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $.getJSON("/Cpanel/Package/GetAirportsByCityId", {
        cityId: $(this).val()
    }, function (data) {
        $this.next(".airports").empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            $this.next(".airports").append("<option value='" + data[i].AirportId + "'>" + data[i].Name + "</option>");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: But I can remember that I have uses $(this) in getjson before. Is this related to jQuery version?

Answer (score 1):

That is because context of select element is lost inside `$.getJSON`. declare the context in variable before getJson call and use it inside success function:

```
var self = $(this);
$.getJSON("/Cpanel/Package/GetAirportsByCityId", {
    cityId: $(this).val()
   }, function (data) {
    self.next(".airports").empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        self.next(".airports").append("<option value='" + data[i].AirportId + "'>" + data[i].Name + "</option>");
    }
});
```

Also if you use `$.ajax` instead of `$.getJSON` then you can use `context` option.